# How to fill a spreadsheet with the information from another spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

Given a main spreadsheet table initialized as

| code | property A | property B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 |  |  |
| A002 |  |  |
| B001 |  |  |
| C001 |  |  |

and another table containing things to update the main table

| code | property A | property B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A002 | foo | bar |
| C001 | baz |  |

how can I import the 2nd table to the main table such that it looks like this:

| code | property A | property B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 |  |  |
| A002 | foo | bar |
| B001 |  |  |
| C001 | baz |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookup functions, for example XLookup. If the samples live in columns A, B, and C on each sheet, first row is labels, start your formula in cell B2 with this

```
=XLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet2!B:B,"")
```

Copy across and down.

The formula locates the code from the cell in column A of the current row in column A of Sheet2 and returns the corresponding value from the same column as the current cell's column. If no such code is found in Sheet2, a blank string is returned.

Note the position of the $ signs. `Sheet2!$A:$A` will stay like that when the formula is copied across, whereas `Sheet2!B:B` will change to `Sheet2!C:C`.

If you have an older version of Excel that doesn't have the XLookup function, you can use Vlookup nested in an error checking function in B2, copied across and down:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE),"")
```

Comment: Given lookup function certainly works! However, since this data will be imported once and never updated again. Is it possible to do it with the Excel import tool? If not possible then I could use copy-and-paste-special on top of lookup.

Comment: If this is a one-time data grab, I would use the formula, then do a copy/paste values. That is a lot faster than wrangling with any import.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the formula `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$G$2:$I$3,COLUMN(B2),0),"")&""`.

[image]

Comment: why the `&""` at the end of the formula? If Vlookup succeeds, the value will be returned with whatever its datatype is. If that data is a number, then your formula will change the number to a text value. That may not be desirable. If Vlookup fails, then you already return an empty string, so why append another one??

Comment: @teylyn Thanks for your explanation. My original intention is to avoid returning 0 when a blank is found.

Comment: Ah, I see. Nice idea, but not usable if it causes numbers to be stored as text. You can easily suppress the display of zero values for the whole sheet, or you can use formatting for the specific cells, or you could check if the lookup returns a 0 and then act accordingly.

Comment: @teylyn Yes, I ignored  the format of results. Thanks for your kind suggestions. :)